# Python - KeyError: 'adm0_a3' when using cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am working to make a map that highlights the countries where we have different kinds of members in the organization I am a part of. I am working with cartopy to make this map and highlight the three types of members as different shapes of blue. 
However, everytime I run this script in the Python Launcher, I keep getting this error:

```
`Samuels-MacBook-Pro:IAPS samuelmathiasborer$ python3 map2018.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "map2018.py", line 303, in <module>
if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] in NCs:
KeyError: 'adm0_a3'`
```

I am not certain why this error is showing because I believe I am using it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

#fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(min_latitude=-57,max_latitude=77,central_longitude=10))
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=.5)
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.95)
#ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)
ax.set_extent([-150, 60, -25, 60])

shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                  category='cultural',
                                  name='admin_0_countries')
reader = shpreader.Reader(shpfilename)
countries = reader.records()



# 3 letter country codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3
# ABW   Aruba
# AFG   Afghanistan
# AGO   Angola
# AIA   Anguilla
# ALA   Åland Islands
# ALB   Albania
# AND   Andorra
# ARE   United Arab Emirates
# ARG   Argentina
# ARM   Armenia
# ASM   American Samoa
# ATA   Antarctica
# ATF   French Southern Territories
# ATG   Antigua and Barbuda
# AUS   Australia
# AUT   Austria
# AZE   Azerbaijan
# BDI   Burundi
# BEL   Belgium
# BEN   Benin
# BES   Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba
# BFA   Burkina Faso
# BGD   Bangladesh
# BGR   Bulgaria
# BHR   Bahrain
# BHS   Bahamas
# BIH   Bosnia and Herzegovina
# BLM   Saint Barthélemy
# BLR   Belarus
# BLZ   Belize
# BMU   Bermuda
# BOL   Bolivia, Plurinational State of
# BRA   Brazil
# BRB   Barbados
# BRN   Brunei Darussalam
# BTN   Bhutan
# BVT   Bouvet Island
# BWA   Botswana
# CAF   Central African Republic
# CAN   Canada
# CCK   Cocos (Keeling) Islands
# CHE   Switzerland
# CHL   Chile
# CHN   China
# CIV   Côte d'Ivoire
# CMR   Cameroon
# COD   Congo, the Democratic Republic of the
# COG   Congo
# COK   Cook Islands
# COL   Colombia
# COM   Comoros
# CPV   Cabo Verde
# CRI   Costa Rica
# CUB   Cuba
# CUW   Curaçao
# CXR   Christmas Island
# CYM   Cayman Islands
# CYP   Cyprus
# CZE   Czechia
# DEU   Germany
# DJI   Djibouti
# DMA   Dominica
# DNK   Denmark
# DOM   Dominican Republic
# DZA   Algeria
# ECU   Ecuador
# EGY   Egypt
# ERI   Eritrea
# ESH   Western Sahara
# ESP   Spain
# EST   Estonia
# ETH   Ethiopia
# FIN   Finland
# FJI   Fiji
# FLK   Falkland Islands (Malvinas)
# FRA   France
# FRO   Faroe Islands
# FSM   Micronesia, Federated States of
# GAB   Gabon
# GBR   United Kingdom
# GEO   Georgia
# GGY   Guernsey
# GHA   Ghana
# GIB   Gibraltar
# GIN   Guinea
# GLP   Guadeloupe
# GMB   Gambia
# GNB   Guinea-Bissau
# GNQ   Equatorial Guinea
# GRC   Greece
# GRD   Grenada
# GRL   Greenland
# GTM   Guatemala
# GUF   French Guiana
# GUM   Guam
# GUY   Guyana
# HKG   Hong Kong
# HMD   Heard Island and McDonald Islands
# HND   Honduras
# HRV   Croatia
# HTI   Haiti
# HUN   Hungary
# IDN   Indonesia
# IMN   Isle of Man
# IND   India
# IOT   British Indian Ocean Territory
# IRL   Ireland
# IRN   Iran, Islamic Republic of
# IRQ   Iraq
# ISL   Iceland
# ISR   Israel
# ITA   Italy
# JAM   Jamaica
# JEY   Jersey
# JOR   Jordan
# JPN   Japan
# KAZ   Kazakhstan
# KEN   Kenya
# KGZ   Kyrgyzstan
# KHM   Cambodia
# KIR   Kiribati
# KNA   Saint Kitts and Nevis
# KOR   Korea, Republic of
# KWT   Kuwait
# LAO   Lao People's Democratic Republic
# LBN   Lebanon
# LBR   Liberia
# LBY   Libya
# LCA   Saint Lucia
# LIE   Liechtenstein
# LKA   Sri Lanka
# LSO   Lesotho
# LTU   Lithuania
# LUX   Luxembourg
# LVA   Latvia
# MAC   Macao
# MAF   Saint Martin (French part)
# MAR   Morocco
# MCO   Monaco
# MDA   Moldova, Republic of
# MDG   Madagascar
# MDV   Maldives
# MEX   Mexico
# MHL   Marshall Islands
# MKD   Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of
# MLI   Mali
# MLT   Malta
# MMR   Myanmar
# MNE   Montenegro
# MNG   Mongolia
# MNP   Northern Mariana Islands
# MOZ   Mozambique
# MRT   Mauritania
# MSR   Montserrat
# MTQ   Martinique
# MUS   Mauritius
# MWI   Malawi
# MYS   Malaysia
# MYT   Mayotte
# NAM   Namibia
# NCL   New Caledonia
# NER   Niger
# NFK   Norfolk Island
# NGA   Nigeria
# NIC   Nicaragua
# NIU   Niue
# NLD   Netherlands
# NOR   Norway
# NPL   Nepal
# NRU   Nauru
# NZL   New Zealand
# OMN   Oman
# PAK   Pakistan
# PAN   Panama
# PCN   Pitcairn
# PER   Peru
# PHL   Philippines
# PLW   Palau
# PNG   Papua New Guinea
# POL   Poland
# PRI   Puerto Rico
# PRK   Korea, Democratic People's Republic of
# PRT   Portugal
# PRY   Paraguay
# PSE   Palestine, State of
# PYF   French Polynesia
# QAT   Qatar
# REU   Réunion
# ROU   Romania
# RUS   Russian Federation
# RWA   Rwanda
# SAU   Saudi Arabia
# SDN   Sudan
# SEN   Senegal
# SGP   Singapore
# SGS   South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
# SHN   Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha
# SJM   Svalbard and Jan Mayen
# SLB   Solomon Islands
# SLE   Sierra Leone
# SLV   El Salvador
# SMR   San Marino
# SOM   Somalia
# SPM   Saint Pierre and Miquelon
# SRB   Serbia
# SSD   South Sudan
# STP   Sao Tome and Principe
# SUR   Suriname
# SVK   Slovakia
# SVN   Slovenia
# SWE   Sweden
# SWZ   Swaziland
# SXM   Sint Maarten (Dutch part)
# SYC   Seychelles
# SYR   Syrian Arab Republic
# TCA   Turks and Caicos Islands
# TCD   Chad
# TGO   Togo
# THA   Thailand
# TJK   Tajikistan
# TKL   Tokelau
# TKM   Turkmenistan
# TLS   Timor-Leste
# TON   Tonga
# TTO   Trinidad and Tobago
# TUN   Tunisia
# TUR   Turkey
# TUV   Tuvalu
# TWN   Taiwan, Province of China
# TZA   Tanzania, United Republic of
# UGA   Uganda
# UKR   Ukraine
# UMI   United States Minor Outlying Islands
# URY   Uruguay
# USA   United States of America
# UZB   Uzbekistan
# VAT   Holy See
# VCT   Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
# VEN   Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of
# VGB   Virgin Islands, British
# VIR   Virgin Islands, U.S.
# VNM   Viet Nam
# VUT   Vanuatu
# WLF   Wallis and Futuna
# WSM   Samoa
# YEM   Yemen
# ZAF   South Africa
# ZMB   Zambia
# ZWE   Zimbabwe

# List each country only once, by the "most significant" membership
NCs = ['AUT','CAN','HRV','FIN','DEU','GRC','HUN','ITA','MKD','MEX','NLD','NOR','PRT','ESP','GBR','IRL','USA']
LCs = ['BEL','CMR','CRI','CZE','DNK','POL','IND','IDN','IRN','TUR','PHL','MLT','NPL','SRB','PAK','ROU','RUS','SVK','SWE','CHE','UKR','GHA','GRL','FRO']
IMs = ['ALB','BEN','BIH','EGY','FRA','GEO','GHA','IDN','LTU','MYS','MAR','NGA','SGP','LKA','VNM','CHN','CYP']
provs = []



# Set the border line width and colors
lwidth = 0.1
NCcolor = [2.0/255, 87.0/255, 250.0/255] # ~IAPS Blue
LCcolor = [30.0/255, 144.0/255, 255.0/255] # Dodger Blue
IMcolor = [0.0/255, 191.0/255, 255.0/255] # Deep Sky Blue
Provcolor = [135.0/255, 206.0/255, 250.0/255] # Light Sky Blue
Othercolor = [196.0/255, 199.0/255, 239.0/255] # Grey

# NCcolor = [2.0/255,87.0/255,250.0/255] # ~IAPS Blue
# LCcolor = [100.0/255, 230.0/255, 100.0/255] # Light Green
# IMcolor = [250.0/255,2.0/255, 153.0/255] # Purple
# Provcolor = [1, 0.5, 0] # Orange
# Othercolor = [196.0/255, 199.0/255, 239.0/255] # Grey

for country in countries:
    if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] in NCs:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=(NCcolor),
                      label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'],linewidth=lwidth)
    elif country.attributes['adm0_a3'] in LCs:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=(LCcolor),
                      label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'],linewidth=lwidth)
    elif country.attributes['adm0_a3'] in IMs:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=(IMcolor),
                      label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'],linewidth=lwidth)
    elif country.attributes['adm0_a3'] in provs:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=(Provcolor),
                      label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'],linewidth=lwidth)
    else:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=(Othercolor),
                      label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'],linewidth=lwidth)

# Add labels
ax.text(-1.9e7,0,'National Committees',
bbox={'boxstyle':'round','facecolor':NCcolor, 'pad':0.6, 'edgecolor':'none'},fontsize=6)
ax.text(-1.9e7,-2.0e6,'Local Committees',
bbox={'boxstyle':'round','facecolor':LCcolor, 'pad':0.6, 'edgecolor':'none'},fontsize=6)
ax.text(-1.9e7,-4.0e6,'Individual Members',
bbox={'boxstyle':'round','facecolor':IMcolor, 'pad':0.6, 'edgecolor':'none'},fontsize=6)
if provs: ax.text(-1.9e7,-6.0e6,'Provisional Committees',
bbox={'boxstyle':'round','facecolor':Provcolor, 'pad':0.6, 'edgecolor':'none'},fontsize=6)

# Save in the same folder as map.png
plt.savefig('map2018.png', format='png', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.savefig('map2018.ps', format='ps', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.savefig('map2018.eps', format='eps', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with 'ADM0_A3' instead of 'adm0_a3'. It seemed to me that they changed it at some point this year.